# NHibenate. How to set IType in Projections.Constant?

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria, ansistring

I have a project using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 with .Net OracleClient, to connect to an old Oracle 8i production database.
I have implemented an ICriteria, that is generating the correct query, but the following internal exception is raised: **System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-12704: character set mismatch**.

```
return Session.
                CreateCriteria<Carrera>().
                SetProjection(Projections.SqlFunction("concat", NHibernateUtil.AnsiString, Projections.Property("Descripcion"), Projections.Constant(s), Projections.Property("Id"))).
                Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Descripcion", filter.Trim(), MatchMode.Anywhere)).
                SetMaxResults(cant).
                List<String>();
```

My question is: How can I declare the IType AnsiString in the arguments of Projections.Constant(object, IType)? I think this could possibly solve the issue. I have tested removing Projections.Constant(), and all works fine.

Sample generated query:

```
    select
    * 
from
    ( SELECT
        (this_.CARR_DESCRIPCION||:p0||this_.CARR_CODIGO) as y0_ 
    FROM
        CARRERAS this_ 
    WHERE
        lower(this_.CARR_DESCRIPCION) like :p1 ) 
where
    rownum <=:p2;
:p0 = ', código: ', :p1 = '%2451%', :p2 = 20
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Projections.Constant(s, NHibernateUtil.AnsiString)` maybe?

Comment: First, sorry for the late response. I tried this but didn't work. The tricky solution that finally work was to insert a numerical constant -999), and then in the results replace every match of the number with the desired string (", código: ").

Comment: return Session.
                    CreateCriteria<Carrera>().
                    SetProjection(Projections.SqlFunction("concat", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Descripcion"), Projections.Constant(-999), Projections.Property("Id"))).
                    Add(Expression.InsensitiveLike("Descripcion", filter.Trim(), MatchMode.Anywhere)).
                    SetMaxResults(cant).
                    List<String>();

Comment: I also tried setting the type with this: NHibernateUtil.GetSerializable(typeof(NHibernate.Type.AnsiStringType))